# Why is InstaPy throwing me a deprecation code when I run session.like_by_tags but not with other code using the same format?

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api, deprecation-warning, instapy

First off, ***I am very new*** to all of this, so if I am missing something please let me know. With that said, I have been experimenting with the InstaPy bot for the past two weeks. It was working perfectly, and the next morning on January 17th, 2022, the `session.like_by_tags` function (is that what it's called?) quit working and I don't understand what happened.

The only new issue is that it would run, and then throw the following error in PowerShell:

[Deprecation Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVgQT.png)

Now then...here is how it all went down

[Fig. 1.1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2oLQ.png)

When I run the `session.follow_user_followers` example, **as shown in Fig. 1.1 above**, everything executes **correctly**, and the bot works.

**However...**

[Fig. 1.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIOMB.png)

When I run `session.like_by_tags` example, **as shown in Fig. 1.2 above**, it **gives me the following error twice**, and then **eventually closes the bot**:

UserWarning: find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead
warnings.warn("find_elements_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_elements() instead")

Comment: InstaPy probably uses [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/) for getting data. Maybe, `session.follow_user_followers()` uses Selenium's `find_elements_by_*(attr)` methods and `session.like_by_tags()` uses `find_elements(By.*(attr))`. Since `find_elements_by_*(attr)` methods are deprecated, the InstaPy methods that use them are deprecated too.